Hukum related to Re-Enslavement of Freed Kafir Slave
السلام عليكم
Is there any specific ahkam related to the re-enslavement of a kafir slave who was freed by his Muslim master but traveled and settled in the land of Dar al Harb & muslim seized him in Jihad or was captured by other Kuffar?
Is it permissible for the Muslims to buy and keep him/her as a slave or he must be set free?
Note: Slave is still Kafir

This question is similar to: Preconditions for freeing a slave in Islam. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@AbduRahman The Question is about Re-Enslavement of Kafir Muslim Due To Circumstances as mentioned!
